# Lambda expression with where clause, how to do a group by

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a lambda expression which returns the records I'm looking for, except that the names are not distinct, so I need to group by name, here is what I have, can someone give me a hand with this.

```
var cities = _context.country.OrderBy(c => c.Name)
            .Where(c => c.Feature_Code != featureCode
                && c.Feature_Code != featureCode2
                && c.Country_Code == CountryCode
                && c.Admin1_code == StateId)
            .Select(c => new CityViewModel
            {
                CityId = c.CountryID,
                CityName = c.Name
            }
        ).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this yet, starting to think I might have to resort to a sql procedure and just call it from my controller.   This would seem to be an easy routine request but so far none of the replies have worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
var cities = _context.country
                     .Where(c => /*Your where conditions*/)
                     .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
                     .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
                     .Select(grp => new CityViewModel
                     {
                         CityId = grp.First().CountryID,
                         CityName = grp.Key
                     });
```

OrderBy should be used after Where.

Comment: This example throws an Unknown column 'Distinct1.Name' in 'where clause' error, but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Also the placement of the OrderBy I really don't think it matters perhaps when used in conjunction with an OrderBy but it works fine either way I'm still getting the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, you could add:

```
.GroupBy(c => c.CityName)
```

Comment: This doesn't work either.  Throws an error on type conversion.

Comment: This to me would be the most logical solution, but it's not working.

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
var cities = _context.country.Distinct(c => c.Name).Where(c => c.Feature_Code != featureCode
            && c.Feature_Code != featureCode2
            && c.Country_Code == CountryCode
            && c.Admin1_code == StateId)
        .Select(c => new CityViewModel
        {
            CityId = c.CountryID,
            CityName = c.Name
        }
```

This should return only one instance of each name.

Comment: I tried this all sorts of ways already, no dice, this doesn't work.